# PowerShell: Compare two CSV files

Tags: powershell, file, csv, compare

Need to compare two csv files and get non matching values using Azure Powershell script. 
Kindly help out. 
1. csv file sample

```
"Network"
"10.4.0.0/16"
"10.10.0.0/16"
"10.37.0.0/16"
"10.80.0.0/16"
```

2. csv file sample

```
"AddressPrefixesText"
  ""10.81.0.0/16"",
  ""10.82.0.0/16"",
  ""10.10.0.0/16"",
  ""10.4.0.0/16"",
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why are the values in example 2 all double quoted? And is that really one column header `AddressPrefixesText`? No header for the second (empty) column there? Please also show us what you have already tried.

Comment: Two different column names in csv files which has IP address list. While comparing we need to remove double quotes and check for IP matching alone.

Comment: Tried below script didnt work as expected. 
$fileA = "E:\Validation\ER1.csv"
$fileB = "E:\Validation\LocalGateway1.csv"
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content $fileA) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content $fileB) -IncludeEqual | Export-csv "E:\Validation\output.csv"

Comment: @kirthi29 - PLEASE, always put your code in the Question so that it can be easily read. plus, wrap it in code formatting markers. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something like below should do it:

```
$fileA = 'E:\Validation\ER1.csv'
$fileB = 'E:\Validation\LocalGateway1.csv'

# FileA can be imported as-is
$csvA = Import-Csv -Path $fileA
# FileB needs treatment after importing
$csvB = Import-Csv -Path $fileB | Select-Object @{Name = 'Network'; Expression = {$_.AddressPrefixesText -replace '[\s"]'}}

# now that we have equal looking objects, you can compare them
$result =  Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $csvA.Network -DifferenceObject $csvB.Network -PassThru -IncludeEqual | ForEach-Object {
    $where = switch ($_.SideIndicator) {
        '=='  { 'Both files' }
        '<='  { "File $fileA" }
        '=>'  { "File $fileB" }
    }
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Network'    = $_
        'WhereFound' = $where
    }
}

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'E:\Validation\output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen:

```
Network      WhereFound                          
-------      ----------                          
10.10.0.0/16 Both files                          
10.4.0.0/16  Both files                          
10.81.0.0/16 File E:\Validation\LocalGateway1.csv
10.82.0.0/16 File E:\Validation\LocalGateway1.csv
10.37.0.0/16 File E:\Validation\ER1.csv          
10.80.0.0/16 File E:\Validation\ER1.csv
```